# Azure service bus subscription metrics

Tags: c#, sdk, azureservicebus

I am trying to find the best way to see the last date a subscription in a topic was accessed via c# (SDK or otherwise) i.e. to purge the queue if not accessed in over x hours. I know there is that functionality built into the service bus explorer but have not been able to find any SDK functionality. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

[image: Service Bus Explorer example]

Comment: There are many Service Bus SDKs available. Can you please tell which SDK are you using?

Comment: At the moment only using the Microsoft.ServiceBus library available that I downloaded via Nuget. Have it creating a connection to the subscription in question using the code below thats working grand.

                       ` _subscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnString, topic, subscriptionNameLegal);`

but the _subscriptionClient  class does not have access to these functions such as purge or even the metrics.

Comment: Do you mean [`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/) or [`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus)?

Comment: Apologies, it WindowsAzure.ServiceBus version 6.0.0. (comes up as Microsoft.ServiceBus in my references for some reason)

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` which is the latest SDK?

Comment: Yes I should be able to, will try now. Does the SDK above give the functionality to check when a sub was last accessed?

Comment: `Does the SDK above give the functionality to check when a sub was last accessed?` - Yes. Please check my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see the code below. It uses [`Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/) SDK. The properties you're interested in is available in [`SubscriptionRuntimeProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.subscriptionruntimeproperties?view=azure-dotnet) class.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString =
                "connection-string";
            string topicName = "topic-name";
            string subscriptionName = "subscription-name";
            ServiceBusAdministrationClient administrationClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
            var result = await administrationClient.GetSubscriptionRuntimePropertiesAsync(topicName, subscriptionName);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Value.AccessedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that all worked perfectly thanks very much for your help! Have accepted this answer + upvoted